# ANDROID_GINGERBREAD in ECLIPSE: Invalid resource directory name

Tags: ros, eclipse, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to upload ros android tutorials on an android device. I am doing this uploading through eclipse as it is the programming environment my android device is synchronized with. In order to do this, I followed the instructions on this page: http://answers.ros.org/question/2178/rosjavajar-missing-certain-packages

I succesfully downloaded the ros android packages from https://android.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/

I have successfully applied rosmake to android_tutorial-camera, android_tutorial_image_transport, android_tutorial_pan_tilt_camera, android_tutorial_pubsub.

I have also successfully applied rosmake to android_gingerbread, as these tutorials require this package.

After having applied rosmake, I imported these tutorials and android_gingerbread as new projects inside eclipse.

However, I get an exception with the android_gingerbread project:

invalid resource directory name: /home/imre/workspace/android_gingerbread/res/index.html (AAPT problem)

Here is a definition of AAPT: "The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML files for your Activities, and compiles them."

The problem seems to come from the content of the index.html file, which lists the following resources: drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, layout, values.

How is it possible to fix this issue with the index.html file of the resources of the android_gingerbread ros package?

I thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11778/android_gingerbread-in-eclipse:-invalid-resource-directory-name/) by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem. I deleted the index.html file. This corrected the error.

---

Originally posted by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) with karma: 26 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0